# How do I get Go's net/http package to stop removing double slashes?

Tags: http, go

Consider the following very basic "net/http"-program:

```
package main

import (
    "net/http"
    "log"
)

func entry(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    log.Println(req.URL.Path)
    path := []byte(req.URL.Path)    
    w.Write(path)
}

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", entry)
    err := http.ListenAndServe("localhost:10000", nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("ListenAndServe: ", err)
    }
}
```

When accessing the URL, `http://localhost:10000/a//b`, the `DefaultServerMux`, which is what the default `HandleFunc()` and `ListenAndServe()` uses, redirects it to `/a/b`, effectively removing the double slash.

The [documentation for `ServerMux`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#ServeMux) does specify that it 'sanitises' URL requests:

> ServeMux also takes care of sanitizing the URL request path, redirecting any request containing . or .. elements or repeated slashes to an equivalent, cleaner URL.

But what if I don't want it to?  I have a scenario where `//` != `/` in my URLs.  I could find another solution.  But is there a way to still use Go's "net/http" package, while it not sanitising my URLs like this?  Preferably with as little re-writing as possible.

(I will probably find a different solution than having `//` and `/` being distinct, since I am probably happy with other features that `ServerMux` provides (in case a solution requires me to use another multiplexer), but now I am curious whether there is a solution with Go's standard "net/http" package.)

Comment: I don't think so if using `//` slash will be a good url indeed.

Comment: It really shouldn't do that, except perhaps for `http.FileServer` (because `//` is equivalent to `/` when the OS resolves a file path). A path with an empty segment is perfectly valid according to RFC 3986.

Comment: @MichaelHampton If @Himanshu's answer is accurate, it would seem it uses path's `Clean()` function, we acts upon the path as if it was a file path.  For instance, if you accessed `/../`, it would redirect you to `/`.

Comment: Write your own mux (aka router) or find a third party mux that does not clean the path.

Answer (score 2):

Go for gorilla mux to route the server using the url. By default the `DefaultSeveMux` uses [Clean](https://golang.org/src/path/path.go?s=2443:2895#L74) which modify the url against various unwanted characters. That's the reason the url changed whn you are using `//` double slash.

```
func Clean(path string) string
```

While if you do not want to sanitize the url. Gorilla mux provide a method SkipClean() which when set to true. It will not sanitize the url.

```
func (r *Router) SkipClean(value bool) *Router {
    r.skipClean = value
    return r
}
```

It is mentioned in the document of gorilla mux for `SkipClean()` as:

> SkipClean defines the path cleaning behaviour for new routes. The
>   initial value is false. Users should be careful about which routes are
>   not cleaned When true, if the route path is "/path//to", it will
>   remain with the double slash. This is helpful if you have a route
>   like: /fetch/http://xkcd.com/534/ When false, the path will be
>   cleaned, so /fetch/http://xkcd.com/534/ will become
>   /fetch/http/xkcd.com/534